# How to fix row_to_name error in R markdown?

Tags: r-markdown

I´m trying to put my code, which runs perfectly, in an R markdown but I keep getting the row_to_name error when I knit, but no when I run the chunk. Honestly I don´t know how to fix it.

The code:

```
homicidios<-read.csv("/Users/julia/Documents/rdoctorado/tasa estatal homicidios.csv",header = TRUE)

#Transform the vector to data frame 

thomicidios<-data.frame(homicidios)

# transpose the matrix To compute stats   

th<-t(homicidios)



#delete first row and set it as header

thomicidios<-row_to_names(th,1,remove_row = TRUE)




#Transform the vector to data frame 

thomicidios2<-data.frame(thomicidios)




#Convert string to integer

thomicidios2[c(1:33)] <- lapply(thomicidios2[c(1:33)], as.integer)

#Summary of the data

summary(thomicidios2)
```

The error is:

Error in row_to_names(th, 1, remove_row = TRUE) :
could not find funtion "row_to_names"
Calls:  ... handle -> withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to add `library(janitor)` within "this" code chunk.